# browser started with puppeteer is not available out of try-catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, puppeteer

Here is the example code:

```
"use strict";
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    console.log(`browser=${browser}`);
    var cnt_pages = (await browser.pages()).length;
    console.log(`${cnt_pages} pages`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    console.error(`can not launch`);
    process.exit();
  }
  console.log(`browser=${browser}`);

  var cnt_pages = (await browser.pages()).length;
  console.log(`cnt_pages ${cnt_pages}`);
  input("continue?");
})();
```

As a result, I get

```
(node:13408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at S:\!kyxa\!code\play_chrome_cdp\nodejs_1\!node_tutorial\!play_async\try_catch_browser.js:15:26
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at emitUnhandledRejectionWarning (internal/process/promises.js:168:15)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:247:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
(node:13408) ReferenceError: browser is not defined
    at S:\!kyxa\!code\play_chrome_cdp\nodejs_1\!node_tutorial\!play_async\try_catch_browser.js:15:26
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:13408) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    at emitDeprecationWarning (internal/process/promises.js:180:11)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:249:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:32)
browser=[object Object]
1 pages
```

As I see, the browser is available and working in the `try` block. But after the `try-catch` block it is not available.

Explain me please what happens?

Comment: I've explored the issue. I define the browser value in the try but I also use it in the catch. consts are block-scoped, so they are tied to the block.

Answer (score 1):

I've explored the issue. I define the browser value in the try but I also use it in the catch. consts are block-scoped, so they are tied to the block. –

This is the working code:

```
"use strict";
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  var browser = null;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    console.log(`browser=${browser}`);
    var cnt_pages = (await browser.pages()).length;
    console.log(`${cnt_pages} pages`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    console.error(`can not launch`);
    process.exit();
  }
  console.log(`browser=${browser}`);

  var cnt_pages = (await browser.pages()).length;
  console.log(`cnt_pages ${cnt_pages}`);
})();
```

Comment: This solves OP's immediate scoping issue but isn't great Puppeteer boilerplate. If the browser throws outside of the try/catch, it's an uncaught error, and the browser is never closed regardless of whether the code throws or not.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize this is a self-answer from OP. Good work figuring it out but comment still applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can elevate `let browser` out of the block and remove the `const`, but even after fixing this scoping issue, the browser resource still isn't closed, and any errors that might occur after the `try`/`catch` blocks are uncaught. Here's my preferred Puppeteer boilerplate that handles these situations:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const scrape = async page => {
  // write your code here
  const url = "https://www.example.com";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  console.log(await page.title());
};

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await scrape(page);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```